# Atualizar dropdown quando janela pop-up é fechada

Tags: javascript, html

No preenchimento de um formulário criei atalhos para adicionar dados nas `dropdowns list` mas quando fecho a janela `pop-up`, faz refresh na página toda.

- Estou a utilizar o seguinte código:

  ***window.onunload = refreshParent;
          function refreshParent() 
  {
              window.opener.location.reload();
          }***

O problema ao actualizar a pagina toda é, limpa os dados que já tinha introduzido. no restante contudo do formulário.
Como fazer para apenas fazer refresh na `dropdown` que adicionamos dados?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que aí você já está falando de Ajax. Uma maneira fácil de usar Ajax é com [jQuery](https://jquery.com)

Você pode usar:

```
$.ajax({

accepts: {

mycustomtype: 'application/x-some-custom-type'

},

// Instructions for how to deserialize a `mycustomtype`

converters: {

'text mycustomtype': function(result) {

// Do Stuff

return newresult;

}

},

// Expect a `mycustomtype` back from server

dataType: 'mycustomtype'

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sim, pode ser feito através de um pedido Ajax mas como faço para só actualizar a dropdown, porque no fundo esse pedido que colocou é semelhante ao que eu fiz mas o que eu fiz foi em javascript.

Comment: Então, depende de como você está recebendo as informações para adicionar no dropdown. Você pode definir um `id` para esse dropdown e com a informação inputada adicionar nele, por exemplo, imagine que o campo é um `input` e que estamos utlizando jQuery, seria algo mais ou menos assim: `$("seuDropdown").find("option").val( $("input").val())`.